# Python - regular expressions - part of the search patern is in same line, part is in the next one

Tags: python, regex

I have 3 emails which have following in email body:

[1st email](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AOxHHLQ1XOr6PZM&cid=3803D1529C72EC2C&id=3803D1529C72EC2C%2169648&parId=root&o=OneUp)

[2nd email](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=3803d1529c72ec2c&id=3803D1529C72EC2C%2169649&authkey=%21AJmOnkR7rwl%5FCQo)

[3rd email](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AizscpxS0QM4hKASTnfv6DCACruInQ)

```
=
```

means new line.There are 3 cases:

**Case 1**
machine name is on the next line

Example

```
 MACHINE: =
ldnmdsbatchxl01
```

**Case 2**

machine name is on the same line:

```
MACHINE: p2prog06
```

**Case 3**

Part of the machine is in the same line, part is in next line

```
MACHINE: p1prog=
07
```

Following  works for first 2 and partial for 3rd case:`regex2 = r'\bMACHINE:\s*(?:=.*)?\s*([^<^\n ]+)`

in 3rd i'm getting `p1prog=`

**> Desired output:**

```
p1prog07
ldnmdsbatchxl01
p2prog06
```

Thanks

```
if resp == 'OK':
        email_body = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
        mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)
        #get all emails with words "PA1" or "PA2" in subject
        if mail["Subject"].find("PA1") > 0 or mail["Subject"].find("PA2") > 0:
                  #search email body for job name (string after word "JOB")
          regex1 = r'(?<!^)JOB:\s*(\S+)'
          regex2 = r'\bMACHINE:\s*(?:=.*)?\s*([^<^\n ]+)|$'
          c=re.findall(regex2, email_body)[0]#,re.DOTALL)
          a=re.findall(regex1 ,email_body)
```

Comment: Try `m=re.search(r'\bMACHINE:\s*(.*(?:\s*^\d+)?)', s, re.M)`, `if m: print(m.group(1).replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""))` ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HbdYuq/1))

Comment: Thanks, it works for 3rd case, but it doesn't print 1st and 2nd, how to combine your regex with mine ?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/cLw0kp. It prints all of them.

Comment: email_body is variable where all email bodies with MACHINE names are stored (examples are in link i posted):`for s in email_body:
            #print s
            m=re.search(r'\bMACHINE:\s*(.*(?:\s*^\d+)?)', s, re.M)
            if m:
             print("Result: " + m.group(1).replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""))` and getting nothing

Comment: Maybe https://ideone.com/TnOX0I will work?

Comment: no errors this time but got only [u'p1prog=07', u'p1prog=07']
[u'=', u'=']

Comment: What does `for s in email_body` mean? You must read the whole file into the memory: `f = open(path_to_file, "r")` and then `s = f.read()`.

Comment: email_body is not stored in file, it's "in memory" variable, i need to "feed" re.search from it. That variable contains multiple email bodies-i posted examples in links

Comment: If you have literal `=` and `=^M` there, just add these to the regex. Like `=(?:\^M)?` just before `(?:\s*^\d+)?`

Comment: yes, i have = and =^M

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/6gySun

Comment: Uh !, finally works, because email bodies contains duplicate MACHINE, how to get only first match, ie. to remove duplicates ?

Comment: Use `list(set(...))`, see https://ideone.com/bcjXQ1

Comment: it works !!!, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
email = 'MACHINE: =\nldnmdsbatchxl01\n\n\nMACHINE: p2prog06\n\n\nMACHINE: p1prog=^M\n07'
res = list(set([re.sub(r'=(?:\^M)?|[\r\n]+', '', x) for x in re.findall(r'\bMACHINE:\s*(.*(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)\S+)?)', email, re.M)]))
print(res)
# => ['ldnmdsbatchxl01', 'p2prog06', 'p1prog07']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jqze2P)

The regex used is [`\bMACHINE:\s*(.*(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)\S+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/J17eQ2/1):

- `\bMACHINE` - whole word `MACHINE`
- `:` - a `:` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)\S+)?)` - Group 1 (this substring will be returned by `re.findall`):

  - `.*` - 0+ chars other than line break chars
  - `(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)\S+)?` - an optional substring:

    - `(?:\r\n?|\n)` - a CRLF, LF or CR line break sequence
    - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars

The `re.sub(r'=(?:\^M)?|[\r\n]+', '', x)` removes `=` or `=^M` and CR/LF symbols from the Group 1 value.

To get unique values, use `list(set(res))`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer:

```
regexp = re.compile('MACHINE:\s={0,1}\s{0,1}((\S+=\^M\s\S+|\S+))')
value = regexp.search(data)[1]
value.replace('=^M\n', ''))
```

#### Long answer:

Assume we have data from your examples:

```
data = """
BFAILURE       JOB: p2_batch_excel_quants_fx_daily_vol_check_0800 MACHINE: =
ldnmdsbatchxl01 EXITCODE:  268438455
(...)
RUNALARM      JOB: p2_credit_qv_curve_snap MACHINE: p2prog06

Attachments:
(...)
[11/01/2019 08:15:09]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM            ALARM: JO=^M
BFAILURE       JOB: p1_static_console_row_based_permissions MACHINE: p1prog=^M
07        EXITCODE:  1<br>^M
"""
```

Then we may use code:

```
import re

regexp = re.compile('MACHINE:\s={0,1}\s{0,1}((\S+=\^M\s\S+|\S+))')

for d in data.split("(...)"):
    value = regexp.search(d)[1]
    print(value.replace('=^M\n', ''))
```

As you see regexp match =^M\n too, so we need to remove it after.

output:

```
ldnmdsbatchxl01
p2prog06
p1prog07
```

#### EDIT:

if your data contains many email bodies in one string:

```
import re

regexp = re.compile('MACHINE:\s={0,1}\s{0,1}((\S+=\^M\s\S+|\S+))')

matches = regexp.findall(data)
print(matches)

print('---')

for m in matches:
    print(m[0].replace('=^M\n', ''))
```

produce:

```
[('ldnmdsbatchxl01', 'ldnmdsbatchxl01'), ('p2prog06', 'p2prog06'), ('p1prog=^M\n07', 'p1prog=^M\n07')]
---
ldnmdsbatchxl01
p2prog06
p1prog07
```

Comment: `email_body = data[0][1].decode('utf-8') regexp = re.compile('MACHINE:\s={0,1}\s{0,1}((\S+=\^M\s\S+|\S+))') for d in email_body:
    value = regexp.search(d)
    print(value)`  getting bunch of None  email_body is list containing message body for multiple emails

Comment: if you have many emails bodies in one string try:
`regexp = re.compile('MACHINE:\s={0,1}\s{0,1}((\S+=\^M\s\S+|\S+))')    machines =regexp.findall(email_body)`

Comment: getting [(u'p1prog=', u'p1prog='), (u'p1prog=', u'p1prog=')]
[(u'=', u'='), (u'=', u'=')]

Comment: `(u'p1prog=', u'p1prog=')` is what is expected.
Look at edited post above.
And about `u'=',` - I can't help without knowing how look line that produces this.

Comment: no, i need p1prog07 and ldnmdsbatchxl01 ( i have these two in email_body variable)

Comment: I understand, `=` is not expected by you there. May you attach exactly this data/file that you are using? Then I may check on same input data as you.

Comment: at begging of question you have links to all 3 cases (MS One Drive) 1st email-3rd email)

Comment: Still looks correct: here is regexp and your data copied: https://regex101.com/r/1S1KI1/1

Comment: Thanks, but @Wiktor Stribiżew last answer helped, it only removes duplicates

Comment: Wiktor, i have another issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201665/python-how-to-extract-multiple-strings